# How to pass value from html to controller in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular and I am trying to show a table based on toggle button value.
i used angular material  to create a toggle button, but i am not able to figure out on how to pass this data onto my controller.

Any help would be appreciated.
Please find my code below
Thanks in Advance...!!!

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup"[(value)]="groupValue">
   <mat-button-toggle value="active">Active</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle value="inactive">Inactive</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`onFilterChange`**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group 
      (change)="onFilterChange(group.value)" 
      [value]="groupValue"
      #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
>
```

Comment: So it means I will have to trigger an event and capture it from there

Comment: Yes you need a function

Comment: Thanks for guiding Sajeetharan, I was thinking we will have something like $scope here as well..!!!

Comment: $scope is not there in angular4 , Mark if the answer helped